# Pass JS-arguments from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arguments

This question is more about good practice. I want to write a JS-Module to plot math-functions onto `canvas`-elements. I know there are several good libraries out there, but I'm new to JavaScript and enjoy math.

The user should use as little JavaScript as possible and I'm wondering how a good JS-library would behave. Would the user have to write a specific `id` for the canvas elements which should be used by the library? What should the user have to do to get a plot from *x = -1* to *x = 1* with grid turned on and green axes?

Would this be a good behavior?

```
<canvas id="plotJS, -1, 1, true, green">
```

I'm pretty sure this is awful, therefore I'm asking. Is there a convenient way to pass arguments to JS in the `html`- code? Something like

```
<canvas id="whatever-i-want" plotJS-xMin="-1" plotJS-xMax="1" plotJS-grid="true" ... >
```

How is this normally done?

Comment: You're looking for `data-*` attributes.

Comment: Okay, this sound good. Could you elaborate?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, I'll take a look real quick.

Comment: @SLaks This seems like a good idea, is this the common way to achieve the effect I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using `JSON` , `data-*` attributes as suggested by @SLaks . At `html` the `data` attribute value is a single `JSON` string, accessible at `javascript` using [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) , `JSON.parse()` ; the `dataset-plot-js` could also be reset at the element using `JSON.stringify()` with parameter being `data-plot-js` attribute string parsed as `javascript` object

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var data = JSON.parse(canvas.dataset.plotJs);

console.log(data);

// change `xMin`
data.xMin = "-2";

canvas.dataset.plotJs = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(canvas.dataset.plotJs);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" data-plot-js='{"xMin":"-1","xMax":"1","grid":"true","color":"green"}'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you really much, I'll probably go with this one.

Comment: @LastSecondsToLive Note, it should also be possible to get , set `data-*` attribute using `canvas.getAttribute("data-plot-js")` and `canvas.setAttribute("data-plot-js", /* data to set */)`